# Reverse Linked List Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I'm implementing a reversed linked list using Javascript.

```
var reverseList = function(head) {
    if (!head || !head.next) {
        return head;
      }
      let tmp = reverseList(head.next);
      //head.next = head;
      head.next.next = head;
      head.next = undefined;
      return tmp;
};
```

The given code is my previous solution, which didn't work. So, I had to go to **.next.next element**. **Why do I need to do it?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If we let the commented line run, it will step back to the previous node.
When you did `head.next = undefined;`, means the last node was the tail of the original list.That is why it would be the head of new reversed list.
[JavaScript: Reverse a Linked List by Will Vincent](https://wsvincent.com/javascript-reverse-linked-list/)